# How to Shadow DOM, if I want to perserve event from outside, but prevent custom event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to use Shadow DOM to encapsulate custom event bubbling but still get the styles from outside.

- I have tried to use slot and found that preserve the outside styles, but cannot encapsulate events.
- I have tried to directly append child to shadowroot, but then I lost all the outside styles.

So what I want to achieve is that ...

- the outside styles can bleed in, in this case span will get color: red
- the custom event 'span-clicked' is blocked by the boundary of the component
- the standard events (such as click) will see the entire component as srcElement

Is there a way that I can achieve all three above? Thank you very much!

```js
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'); 
var shadowroot = outer.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

shadowroot.innerHTML = `
  <slot></slot>
`; 

var spanInsideShadow = document.getElementById('span_inside_shadow'); 
shadowroot.appendChild(spanInsideShadow); 

var spanInLightDom = document.getElementById('span_in_slot'); 

spanInsideShadow.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  spanInsideShadow.dispatchEvent(new Event('span-clicked', {bubbles: true}));
}); 


outer.addEventListener('span-clicked', function(e){
  console.log('outer received custom event. Do not want this!'); 
}); 

outer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('click event received, source elem = ', e.srcElement); 
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'>
    <span id='span_light_dom'> SPAN_IN_LIGHT_DOM_BUT_RENDERED_IN_SLOT </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
<span id='span_normal'>A_NORMAL_SPAN_OUTSIDE </span>
</div>

<div>
<span id='span_inside_shadow'>SPAN_WILL_BE_APPENDED_TO_SHAODOW_ROOT</span>
</div>
```

I hope I am explaining myself clear enough. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The desired behaviour is exactly what I see in Chrome & Safari.

Are you getting differing results? See https://jsfiddle.net/8fhtx5g7/ for a demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b8ct5sfp/1/ did the same and getting same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The only way to auto-convert your event target and to get outside styles into Shadow DOM is to include all of the DOM and the CSS in the Shadow DOM. And not by using `<slot>`.

If you are loading an external CSS file through the `<link>` tag then you can include that same `<link>` tag in your shadow DOM.

If you are including a `<style>` tag in your main page then you need to include a `clone` of that `<style>` tag inside your shadow DOM.

As I write this, the only other option you have is to use CSS variables that will allow the outside world to change values of the inner CSS. But then you have to write your CSS to use variables.

No matter which way you chose you can only affect the styling of elements within the Shadow DOM if you copy those styles in or affect them through CSS variables. If you don't include some new, unexpected, CSS then it will not be applied.

And since you want the Shadow DOM to convert the target of your events you must place the DOM inside the shadow and not by using `<slot>`.

There are other methods being worked on, but those won't be out for some time. Probably several years.

I hope this answers your question. Unfortunately I don't think this is what you wanted to find out.